# To find out the total distance

Tags: java

I have a java code for sum the two given distances(feet, inch).I want to find out the total distances between two point.

I have a code in which I want to sum up two distances and find out the total distance. but this code could not provide me my desired answer.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Distance {
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    int feet;int inches;
    public void setDistance()
    {
        System.out.print("enter feets:");
        int f=input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter inches :");
        int i=input.nextInt();
    }
    public void addDistance(Distance d1,Distance d2)
    {
        feet=d1.feet+d2.feet+(inches/12);
        inches=d1.inches+d2.inches;
        inches=inches%12;
    }
    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println("feets :"+feet+"\tinches :"+inches);
    }
}
```

```
public class Home_Actvity3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Distance d1=new Distance();
        Distance d2=new Distance();
        Distance d3=new Distance();
        System.out.println("Enter first distance :");
        d1.setDistance();
        System.out.println("Enter second distance :");
        d2.setDistance();
        System.out.println("Total distance :");
        d1.addDistance(d1, d2);
        d3.display();

    }

}
```

when I enter these value as input. I  my desired answer.

```
run:
Enter first distance :
enter feets:2
Enter inches :5
Enter second distance :
enter feets:3
Enter inches :7
Total distance :
feets :0    inches :0
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 24 seconds)
```

I want that answer

```
total distance:
feets :6        inches :0
```

Comment: This is NO Object Oriented Programming. You should check it.

Comment: Your addDistance(d1, d2) function is not part of an object, is more like a class function.

Comment: By the way, this question made me wonder if there is a [Java library for representing and calculating lengths](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/61484/1255).

Comment: you created 3 separate new objects. d3 would not contain any of the inputs you added in d1 and d2. if you want it to display from what you added to d1. You should have used d1.display() instead of d3.display() to get the right result. Even then, you should re-write your class to hold several inputs in an array and compute the display from there.

Comment: dear Frank why you tell me to use d1,display() instead of d3.display(). purpose of my question is straight forward that the user enter two different inputs and code return the sum of these two distances.and why you recommend me to use array. i have not large number of inputs, i have only two inputs. please clarify solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your code fragment:

```
System.out.print("enter feets:");
int f=input.nextInt();
System.out.print("Enter inches :");
int i=input.nextInt();
```

Variables i and f are NOT a class members.

```
System.out.print("enter feets:");
int f=input.nextInt();
feet = f;
System.out.print("Enter inches :");
int i=input.nextInt();
inches = i;
```

that's right!

Comment: i cant understand  your answer please tell me this in detail.